# In the python fractions module, why is a result of round() sometimes incorrect?

Tags: python, rounding, fractions

round(fractions.Fraction("3.50")) yields 4, as one would expect. But round(fractions.Fraction("49886.50")) yields 49886, not 49887. What gives?

Comment: Probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen No, has nothing to do with that.